# Shell script called using Python subprocess call() takes no effect

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, subprocess

I am having problems executing a shell script using subprocess.call() and I made this test in Python console to try to figure out which is the problem:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call(["touch", "/tmp/out.txt"])
```

This works and creates the file in tmp folder. However, none of these two calls work:

```
subprocess.call(["sh", "/tmp/test.sh"])
subprocess.call(["/tmp/test.sh"])
```

/tmp/test.sh:

```
#!/bin/bash
touch out.txt
exit 0
```

Basically, executing an script from subprocess.call() is not producing any output. I gave full permissions to files and folders to avoid any problem. It seems the problem may be related to the user executing the script, but it is the same user as in the first case, which is working.
Any idea what the problem could be?

BTW, I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS, Python 2.7.4.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This should create a `test.sh` on your cwd, not on your `/tmp`.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. I expect the file out.txt to be created in /tmp folder. I don't get any error accessing the script file, so the path is correct, however, the file is not created.

Comment: "... executing an script from subprocess.call() is not producing any output" -- your shell script does not include anything that should produce any output, so I'm not sure why this is surprising...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your script is executed correctly. The problem is with your `bash` script.

You have to understand that this script inherits working directory of the parent script. Therefore `out.txt` will be created in the directory where you run the python script which makes use of `subprocess.call`.

Comment: Correct. As utdemir pointed out, the file out.txt is created in my cwd, which is home folder for my user.